# Cannot import local module python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to import local modules in python but for some reason it cannot find the modules. I know that you can import them by adding them to your path with sys. But I don't want to use sys for this.
My file structure looks like this

```
scraper_backend
    - jobs
        - extract.py
        - load.py
        - models.py
        - transform.py
        - url_builder.py
main.py
```

my main.py looks like this.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from scraper_backend.jobs import extract, load, transform


def main():
    # Extract
    wind = extract.extract_wind(datetime.now())
    solar = extract.extract_solar(datetime.now())
    # Transform
    date = extract.round_dt(datetime.now()) - timedelta(minutes=15)
    df = transform.update_file(date, wind, solar)
    # Load
    load.write_to_path(df, "energy.parquet")

main()
```

For the moment im using

```
sys.path.append("scraper_backend//jobs")
```

But when I remove the sys.path.append it gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scraper_backend.jobs`.
Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a file called `__init__.py` in the jobs folder. This tells python that the directory is a package which can be imported.

For example, if you have the following directory structure:

```
scraper_backend
    - jobs
        - __init__.py
        - extract.py
        - load.py
        - models.py
        - transform.py
        - url_builder.py
```

Then you can import the jobs package like this:

from scraper_backend.jobs import extract, load, transform